# How to visualize optional fields in a horizontal searchform

Tags: forms, search, travel, optional-fields

The user does not have to fill in the date/adults/childs/rooms, they are optional. The user can also search with only filling in the destination (left box).

How would you visualize that?

[image]

Comment: what's the emphasis here for business value? Is there more value in destination queries, without the date/people details? Or even though it's optional, are you actively trying to get them to fill the other fields out?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the dates and rooms fields are defaulted to say "No Specific Dates" and "No Specific Room Size" (or something along those lines).

That makes it clear that they are optional and the user can precede without selected them.

When the user clicks either of them, you can then allow them to specify the values as you currently do and they will show relevant text to reflect the selected values.

Don't forget to include a way to reset them back to "No Specific..." values too.

Answer (score 1):

While the filling field is white, which means an active area, you can set the optional areas as inactive using other colors or textures. They will became active only when the user clicks on them.

[image]

Or optional with a dashed border:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there's not only just a single issue or solution to consider here.

- First, **`the importance of the Search field`** should be given to the user via `it's size`,
- For the same considerations, date-timepicker icon and person-counter should be preferred smaller,
- Then the color of the `Search button` and the rest of the secondary important information can be chosen same to give the user the **ability and feeling of selecting defaults**,
- In that particular situation lastly, I'd prefer to use the main Search area in contrary color to differentiate, so that user may only type where to he/she would go without needing the rest.

> Besides having the aspects mentioned above, users would
> intuitively see defaultly selected values and may apply change if they
> want.

[image]